# Completion^ block not being called in UIView animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiimageview, block

Is there something I'm missing here?
i want the imageview to slide in then slide out from the bottom of the screen.

also, this seems to put the UIImageView behind the navigation bar how can I make a CGRect to fit the screen under the navbar?

```
_finga = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-88)];
hiddenFrame = CGRectOffset(_finga.frame, 0, _finga.frame.size.height);
_finga.frame = hiddenFrame;
[self.view addSubview:_finga];
_finga.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Finga"];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    _finga.frame = self.view.bounds;
}completion:^(BOOL done) {
    if (done) {
        NSLog(@"Complete!");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
            _finga.frame = hiddenFrame;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint in the animation block, and set one in the completion block (before the if (done) test), you're saying you hit only the first one?

Comment: Where is this code? What method is it in?

Comment: I put a breakpoint at the `if (done)` line and it says `done = NO`

Comment: its in its own function, it gets called in `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

Comment: I called this function after a delay and now it seems to work - perhaps the UIView elements I am animating did not exist at the point of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CGRect you initialize `_finga` with would put it under the nav bar. In the animation, you are setting the frame to the bounds of the view, which would put it behind the bar, since the y value would be 0.

You could write less code by initializing `_finga` with this frame from the start:

```
CGRectMake(0,
           self.view.bounds.size.height,
           self.view.bounds.size.width,
           self.view.bounds.size.height-88);
```

That will put the view off the screen. Then after you add it as a subview and set its image, animate the view back up to this frame:

```
CGRectMake(0,
           88,
           self.view.bounds.size.width,
           self.view.bounds.size.height-88);
```

Which will put the view just below the nav bar. Consider also replacing all the hard coded 88s with a variable or `#define` so that you can play around with it more easily and in case the nav bar height ever changes.

As for the completion block, try logging that `@"Complete!"` string before you check if `done` is `YES`, or put a breakpoint there and see what the value of `done` is. Your animation may not be completing for some reason, which would explain why the code in the completion block is not being run.

Generally, though, if you are just using the completion block to run another animation after the first one, you don't need to check the done `BOOL` at all. It's only crucial when something else in your program depends on the state of the animation. For example, the user may click a button which animates something and then takes the user to a different section of the app. But if the user cancels the animation, you may not want to go to the other section after all, so you can check `done`.